# Using a for-in loop with NSInteger?

Tags: ios5, for-in-loop

I have an NSMutableArray populated with NSIntegers. I need to loop through the array. I could do:

```
// given NSMutableArray *array of NSIntegers
NSUInteger n = [array count];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  NSInteger x = [array objectAtIndex:i];
  // query SQLite WHERE id = x
}
```

However, it seems that a for (object in array) loop would be cleaner. iOS 5 does not accept NSIntegers or NSNumbers as objects in for-in loops. Should I loop through the array with NSObjects, casting the NSObject to an NSInteger during each iteration? Is there another way? Or is a for loop like the one above the cleanest solution to this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Objective-C you can use a for-in loop with NSNumber like this:

```
    NSArray *array = /*NSArray with NSNumber*/;

    for (NSNumber *n in array) {
        NSLog(@"i: %d", [n intValue]);
    }
```

Check this out.

Comment: great thanks. NSNumber still needs to be converted to NSInteger for some operations, but this is nice and clean

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, you will not be allowed to have an NSMutableArray of NSUInteger (aka unsigned long) as it's not an objective-c object.

You may use the c style.

```
NSUInteger array[] = {value1,value2,value3};
int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
   NSInteger value = array[i];
   // do whatever you want
}
```